# Trying to create a text file with the date

Tags: python

I am trying to merge files and after create a new file and name it with the day date.

```
import datetime

import os

filename = datetime.datetime.now()

file1 = open("A1.txt", 'r+')

file2 = open("A2.txt", 'r+')

file3 = open("A3.txt", 'r+')

d1 = file1.read()

d2 = file2.read()

d3 = file3.read()

datac = [d1, d2, d3]

def file_w():   

    with open((filename.strftime("%D") + ".txt" ,'w+')) as file:

    file.write()    

    for i in datac:

        file.write(i)


file_w()
```

Comment: Do you have a *question*? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is the open statement (the parenthesis at near the end):

```
with open((filename.strftime("%D") + ".txt" ,'w+')) as file:
```

should be:

```
with open((filename.strftime("%D") + ".txt") ,'w+') as file:
```

but you might have a problem naming a file with "/" in it, such as generated by the "%D" in the strftime method.  Instead you could try:

```
with open((filename.strftime("%m_%d_%Y") + ".txt") ,'w+') as file:
```